# Flutter Firestore Riverpod Getting Data Issue

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, riverpod

I have a collection of normalads and I'm trying to read all document in this collection

[This code is working fine and printing all the documents in the collection & stopping for loop prints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vRt2.png)

[But when I try to add each document into an array it doesn't work and stopping for loop doesn't print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HddLW.png)

Comment: Please don't post (links to) screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Future<List<NormalAdModel>> getNormalAdsFuture() async{
 final docs = await (firestore.collection("normalads").get()).docs;
 return docs.map((e) => NormalAdModel.fromMap(Map.from(e.data()!))).toList();
}
```

Comment: I solved this yesterday using this exact code, thank you